# Check is Postgres jsonb contain value via Specification

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jsonb, specifications

I have jsonb field in Entity, that actually List<Long>.
How to determine is List contain value?

I'm found "jsonb_array_elements_set" function, but stacked.

```
private static Specification<UserPromoConditionsSpecifications> byLoanIdNotIn(Long loanId){
            return loanId == null ? null : (root, query, cb) ->
                cb.function("jsonb_array_elements_set", Set.class, root.get("loanDataIds"));
        }
```

Thanks in advance